# Not able to install python packages

Tags: 16.04, package-management, python, python-2.7

After running `apt-cache policy python` in Ubuntu 16.04, I got the following results: `python: Installed: 2.7.12-1`, but I'm not able to install any python packages. I'm stuck with this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.12-1 is to be installed
 python-setuptools : Depends: python-pkg-resources (= 20.7.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Results of `sudo apt install python-pkg-resources`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-pkg-resources :  
                     Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54656/discussion-on-question-by-suvi7896-not-able-to-install-python-packages).